# Hashed field not displaying in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, hash, ssrs-2012

I have a query that is using this convert function that correctly displays the data when I preview it in the SSRS Dataset:

```
CONVERT(varchar(255), HashedFileNum, 1) AS HashedFileNum
```

returns values like

```
0x7BB9D2F1A8A1B39832B95B932DD73A31
```

However when I try to add that field to my report I get #ERROR in the field instead of the value.

Any suggestions on getting the value to show in my report?

Comment: Have you tried converting to nvarchar instead? I had a similar issue in the past.

Comment: if you will add that as an answer I will accept it!!

Comment: did it work? The devil is in the details!!

Comment: yes it did :)  - accepted it as the answer

Comment: Beautimus!! Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting to nvarchar instead of varchar; I've had a similar issues in the past.